# Reading persisted data from Apple/Objective-C in C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, objective-c, serialization, nscoder

is there a **C#/.NET library** or otherwise existing code that can **read persisted data from Apple's serialization API**, namely `NSKeyedArchiver, NSKeyedUnarchiver, NSCoder`?

Context: A friend of mine created a cool app for some of the Apple devices. I have a similar app for the Microsoft world and want to import his documents. The data is in a single file containing all necessary content. This file is created with the above mentioned Apple API.

**What is the most simple way of reading Apple's data in C#?**

Thanks, Marcel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If cross-platform reading is your goal, IMO you should use a cross-platform serializer. Xml would be a trivial example (and checking the docs, [may be supported](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0)), so the first thing I'd try is serializing as xml and hacking through what is generated.

If that doesn't work, or you need something more compact then protobuf is available for [Objective-C](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-objc/) ([or another](http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers), and of course there are [several for C#](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns)).

I don't know much about the Apple serialization API, but *platform tied* serializers tend to do a few things that make portability very hard:

- undocumented format (often)
- tied to platform-specific types, requiring re-mapping
- tied to specific names (fields etc) or layouts (byte offset) on the types